# Can I write multivariable limits as functions of single variable limits?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So if I a multivariable limit (I have to prove using an Epsilon-Delta Proof)

$\lim_{(x,y)\to(2,3)} xy = 6$

Can I write this as

$(\lim_{x \to 2}x)\cdot(\lim_{y \to 3}y)=2*3=6$

Is this valid?

Comment: consider to close the question if you find one of the answers useful

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to rewrite a multivariable limit such as $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (2,3)}xy$ as a combination of single-variable limits. This can be shown by the product of limits rule. Hence,

$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (2,3)}xy=6$

$\Leftrightarrow \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (2,3)}x \cdot \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (2,3)}y=6$

$\Leftrightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow 2}x \cdot \lim_{y\rightarrow3}y=6$

$\Leftrightarrow 2 \cdot 3=6$

$\Leftrightarrow 6=6$

So, if you are attempting to prove this with the epsilon definition, then it will not be in vain.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to do this if and only if you proved there exists:

$$lim_{x \to 2}\  x = l_1 \in \mathbb{R}, \ lim_{y \to 3} \  y =l_2 \in \mathbb{R}$$

Answer (score 0):

When limits of each single part exists and we don't face with an indeterminate forms, always we can use algebraic rules, that is

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(2,3)} xy = 2\cdot 3=6$$

We can also extend to other cases when a part doesn't exist, as for example

$$\lim_{|x^2+y^2|\to \infty} \frac1y \cdot{\sin x}  = 0$$

where we are implicitely referring to squeeze theorem.